# Rails 4: Using the amazon-ecs gem to do an ItemSearch (error with AccessKey Id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to work through [this](https://github.com/twler/amazon-ecs-sample) sample app on how to use the [Amazon Product Advertising API (amazon-ecs)](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) gem in Ruby on Rails and I'm getting this returned:

```
Parameter               Value
res                     #<Amazon::Ecs::Response:0x8cda458>
res.is_valid_request?   false
res.has_error?          true
res.error               Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. 
                        Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at 
                        https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-
                        in.html.
res.total_pages         0
res.total_results       0
res.item_page           0
```

I've edited the file in `config/initializers/amazon-ecs.rb` with my own credentials and I've already registered for the Product Advertising API. Am I missing something?